# What is the error in this c code

Tags: c, character-arrays

```
main() {
        char names [5][20] = {
                "rmaesh",
                "ram",
                "suresh",
                "sam"
                "ramu"
        };
char *t;
        t = names[2];
        names[2] = names[3];
        names[3] = t;

        printf(" the array elemsnt are \n");
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
                printf("\n%s", names[i]);
}
```

i am getting below error while compiling this program

```
stringarrary.c: In function ‘main’:
stringarrary.c:12:11: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[20]’ from type ‘char *’
  names[2] = names[3];
           ^
stringarrary.c:13:11: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[20]’ from type    ‘char *’
  names[3] = t;
```

Answer (score 3):

It is illegal to try and assign to an array. In this case you should use the `strcpy` function. Note that your `char *t;` idea does not work either if you intend to swap the two arrays, because it only points at one of your existing strings; as soon as you write over `names[2]`, that data is gone.

```
char t[20];
strcpy(t, names[2]);
strcpy(names[2], names[3]);
strcpy(names[3], t);
```

Also, `"\n%s"` should be `"%s\n"` - you want the newline to come after what you printed. And don't forget to `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <string.h>`.

Answer (score 3):

The error on line 13 is easiest to understand: `names[3]` is an array of `char`; you can't just assign a pointer to it.  On line 12, the compiler is converting `names[3]` to a pointer and trying to assign it to the array `names[2]`, which is likewise can't do.

Try copying the strings instead.  In C, you can't copy arrays using the `=` operator; use the functions from `memcpy` or `strcpy` families.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
main() {
    char names [5][20] = {
        "rmaesh",
        "ram",
        "suresh",
        "sam", //<----- You are missing this (,) at the end 
        "ramu"
    };
char *t;
    strcpy( t, names[2]); // And also use this syntax
    strcpy(names[2] , names[3]);
    strcpy(names[3], t);

    printf(" the array elemsnt are \n");
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
        printf("\n%s", names[i]);
}
```

Comment: You have not allocated any memory to t. You should rather use `char t[20]` or `char *t = malloc(20)` and `free(t)` at end. Your code would cause a segmentation fault.

Comment: Moreover `conio.h` is not a standard file(nor is clrscr)

Comment: @ Mohit Jain But you can not use this `char *t = malloc(20)` syntax in `C compiler`. You could use this `char *t =(char*) malloc(20)`.:D

Comment: @Mohit Jain Moreover `getch();`. We should use these `system("cls")` and `system("pause");` thank you

Comment: You should not [typecast malloc return value to char * as suggested by you in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). Casting in the way suggested by you may leave some difficult to trace bug in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The `names` array is a two-dimensional array of characters.  As the other answers have pointed out, when you want to copy an array of characters, you need to use `memcpy` or `strcpy`.

The alternative solution is to make `names` a one-dimensional array of pointers. The resulting code would look like this.

```
int main( void )
{
    char *names[5] = {
        "rmaesh",
        "ram",
        "suresh",
        "sam",
        "ramu"
    };
    char *t;

    t = names[2];
    names[2] = names[3];
    names[3] = t;

    printf(" the array elemsnt are \n");
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
        printf("\n%s", names[i]);
}
```

The advantage to this method is that it allows you to manipulate the pointers the way you wanted to.  The disadvantage is that the strings are read-only.  Attempting to modify the strings will result in undefined behavior.